# Uploading Images labels

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, csv, labels

I'm uploading images labels using a CSV file contains the following columns (`store`,`sku`,`image_label`,`small_image_label`,`thumbnail_label`) and that's worked perfectly.

The problem is when i have a product contains many images,Only the main image label is changed.But the rest of images labels is not changed.Is there anything i must change in the CSV file to apply labels to all products images?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer is taken from a [blogpost](https://www.integer-net.com/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/) by [avstudnitz](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2207/andreas-von-studnitz)

> Importing product images has only been possible since Magento versions
>   1.6 (CE) and 1.11. The images that are to be imported need to be available in the media/import folder. The corresponding rows of the
>   import file need to look like this:
>
> ```
>     sku | _media_image | _media_attribute_id | _media_is_disabled | _media_position | _media_lable | image    | small_image | thumbnail
> 1234567 |     img1.jpg |                  77 |                  1 |               1 |      Image 1 | img1.jpg |    img2.jpg |  img2.jpg
>         |     Img2.jpg |                  77 |                  0 |               2 |      Image 2 |        
>         |     Img3.jpg |                  77 |                  0 |               3 |      Image 3 |
> ```
>
> Some annotations:
>
> - The file name of the image that is to be imported is listed in the _media_image column.
> - The _media_attribute_id column required the ID of the product attribute “image_gallery”. It can be obtained either from the admin
>     panel or your custom modules using the expression
>     `Mage::getSingleton(‘catalog/product’)-getResource()->getAttribute(‘media_gallery’)->getAttributeId();`
> - The typing error _media_lable is intentional and hard-wired into Magento
> - In the image,small_image, and thumbnail columns, the first row contains the file names of the according main images.
> - Unfortunately, existing images can not be deleted using the module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But i didn't get your conclusion.Can i upload the rest images labels?

Comment: I thought I answered that, you need extra rows under the first row like for Img2.jpg and Img3.jpg with _media_image, _media_attribute_id, _media_is_disabled, _media_position, _media_lable set. Note the mis-spelling of label